# How to create onClick in Fragment

Tags: java, android

I'm writing a project in which there is a fragment that contains a button, I don't know how to make an onclick method, please help

Comment: Have you checked the documentation or any other resource? Using Buttons and Fragments in android are quite popular topics.

Comment: Please share the code that you have tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- you can put an `onClick` code on a button by using the `setOnClickListener` method and provide the code you want inside it like this.
- assuming your button id is **btn** in the xml layout, getting a reference to the button depends on how you inflate your layout in the `onCreateView` method.

if you're using a view inflater the code to get a reference to the button might look like this :

```
public class YourFragment extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_layout_name, container, false);
       Button btn = rootView.findViewById(R.id.btn);
       btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //write your code here
            }
        });
        return rootView ;
    }
}
```

if you're using a binding to inflate your layout, the code might look like this:

```
public class YourFragment extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       YourLayoutNameBinding binding = YourLayoutNameBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false);
       Button btn = binding.btn ;
       btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //write your code here
            }
        });
      return binding.getRoot();
    }
}
```

you can get more information about buttons from the [android developers documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/button)